# New compressor stiff out the box

Tags: ac, dodge, b350

I just got a new compressor because I’m replacing everything in a contaminated AC system. So I’m replacing expansion valve, drier, condenser, evaporator, and of course the compressor, and cleaned the lines. But, the compressor straight out the box is really hard to turn. I probably have to put 20 pounds of force on it to turn the clutch. I removed the oil and put the proper amount pag 46 in. It’s still fairly stiff. I was already having issues where my van’s performance got worse with the AC on. So, I don’t want a compressor that’s going to put even more strain than the old one. If this is normal for a new compressor, I’d like some confirmation on that before I install. Thank you.

Comment: Knowing the year/make/model of the vehicle in question could help you with your issue.

Comment: 1994 Dodge B350

Comment: I take it you are spinning the pulley without the clutch engaged? If it spins hard without the clutch engaged, the bearing may be tweaked and should be replaced. Without the clutch engaged, it should spin freely.

Comment: The pulley is always free to turn. Does it or not? The front clutch plate is bolted to the compressor shaft and will have some resistance to rotation since you're turning the compressor with oil in it. If oil settled in the wrong places, resistance may be due to hydraulic lock. Sit the compressor on its clutch and allow oil to migrate elsewhere for a few minutes then try turning it. You may have to put it on its rear for the same reason until the compressor rotates. If none of this frees up whatever restricts rotation, return it for replacement stating it seized before installation.